# How to use JWT token with axios on React Native

Tags: node.js, rest, react-native, authentication

I did a REST api using node.js and express, I started trying to build user authentication so I used JWT. Now, I'm trying to build a React Native application, but keep getting Error 401 Access Denied. Here's where I receive the JWT token:

```
...
import api from '../services/api';

export default function Login({ navigation }) {

const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken').then(authToken => {
        if (authToken) {
            navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
        }
    });
}, []);

async function handleSubmit() {
    try {
        const response = await api.post('/login', {
            email,
            password
        });


        const authToken = response.data;

        await AsyncStorage.setItem('authToken', response.data);

        if (authToken) navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
    } catch (err) {

    }

}
...
```

Here's where I need authentication, but I can't seem find out how to send authToken and get response from the api.

```
...
import api from '../services/api';

export default function List({ navigation }) {

useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('authToken').then(authToken => {
        if (!authToken) {
            navigation.navigate('Login');
        }
    });
}, []);

async function handleSubmit() {
    const response = await api.post('/tasks', {
        "description": "Finish this shit",
        "priority": 3,
        "completed": false
    });

    console.log(response.data);
}
...
```

Comment: I didn't see where you utilize the authToken. Please show the code of services/api.